# Problema de quebra de linha no bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho um slide do bootstrap que gostaria de adicionar 2 linhas e cada linha teria 3 elementos. Depois para ver o restante dos elementos, a pessoa teria que clicar na seta e passar para o lado. **O meu problema é:** eu não consigo fazer ele ter 2 linhas, o slide fica com todos os elementos em uma só linha. E também não consigo adicionar a seta para passar para o lado, visto que todos os elementos já estão em uma mesma linha.

O resultado final deveria ser assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*com 2 linhas e 3 elementos em cada linha. o leitor teria que clicar na seta para ver o restante dos elementos*

Abaixo está o código que estou usando e que está com o problema.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
        
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
            
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
            
             
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
             
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
             
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
            
            
          </ul>

<div class="controls-top">
<a class="btn-floating" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i
    class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="btn-floating" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i
    class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
            </div>
        
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
            
               <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
            
               <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
            
               <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu não entendi essa parte "eu não consigo fazer ele ter 2 linhas, o slide fica com todos os elementos em uma só linha. " Como deveria ser o resultado final? E não tem as setas pe vc simplesmente não colocou nada, ou qual elemento deveria ser a sua seta, cade o seu Next e Previous?

Comment: @hugocsl boa noite! Primeiramente obrigada pela resposta. Atualizei a pergunta e coloquei uma imagem de como o resultado deveria ser. Sobre as setas, tambem adicionei mas nao funcionam. As setas deveriam funcionar nos primeiros quadrinhos e nao no grandão

Answer (score 0):

Para ter duas linhas é necessário que você a class row, vou dar um exemplo prático:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container">   
        
    
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">
    
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" ><a href="#">About<small><img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200"></small></a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small><img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200"></small></a></li>
            
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small><img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200"></small></a></li>
            

          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">  
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><a href="#">Portfolio<small><img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200"></small></a></li>
                        
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"><a href="#">Portfolio<small><img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200"></small></a></li>
                
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"><a href="#">Portfolio<small><img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200"></small></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff" />
            </div>
        
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
            </div>
        
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
            
               <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
            
               <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
            
               <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Recomendo você atualizar o código para a versão do Bootstrap 4.0.
Como o 3.3 é um pouco ruim para fazer o slider, recomendo utilizar essa dependência:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/